# ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined

Tags: caching, javascript

I am working on a production site, moving settings from a development site for a mobile environment. However, I am receiving the above error. I can not figure out what is causing this error. It does not matter what theme I change my jquery mobile environment too. I've checked all the modules and they seem to be the same versions. The only thing I can see that is different is in the development site I can uncheck/check the block cache, on the production environment I can not do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with the ordering of the javascript files. Drupal is defined in

`/misc/Drupal.js`

```
var Drupal = Drupal || { 'settings': {}, 'behaviors': {}, 'locale': {} };
```

Check Drupal.js is added to your HTML source, prior to when that variable is requested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if that was the issue or if I was having issues with htaccess. Either way I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

In drupal 8 you might have to add core/drupal as a dependency of your module.

```
your-custom-module:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/your_custom_module.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same problem installing a drupal 7 web site from a dump.

The original `default` folder was provided empty for sizes management.
After pushing in the `settings.php` file and the `files` directory the `Drupal is not defined` error was there.

Originally the developers had two other folders inside the `default` folder.

When restored this folders the error was solved.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @David Thomas, this is an issue with file `misc/drupal.js`. Drupal by default puts it into the correct order. So most likely, the file is not accessible by your web server. Create its URL and try accessing it in your browser, and you will see.

In my case, this was due to using PHP-FPM (which runs with user rights similar to `mod_suphp`), and forgetting that static files (`png, jpg, css, js etc.) are still served by apache2 in my case. So these needed to be world-readable.